# How did the Registers get their names?

Tags: data-structures

I'm interested in how the computer registers got their names, for example:
eax and ebx. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is probably not the best site for this interesting question.

Comment: I don't see how this is a question about computer science. While we do take questions about the general principles of computer architecture and processor design, the specific naming of a specific CPU's registers isn't that kind of question. At the bottom of this page, you can find links to other Stack Exchange sites. Your question might be on topic at one of those -- check the help centre of any site that looks promising.